# Porque al utilizar comillas dobles o simples en Ruby on Rails cambia el resultado que se imprime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Porque al variar la sintaxis del código utilizando comillas dobles o simples cambia el resultado que se imprime ?

```
<puts"hola \n nueva "
puts'hola \n nueva '>
```

Answer (score 1):

En ruby hay distinción entre comillas dobles y simples. Si utilizas comillas dobles se evalúa el contenido y se ejecuta el código interpolado entre #{}, de haberlo.

Igualmente no funcionarán las secuencias de escape como los \n, por ejemplo. Por eso se te muestran distintos resultados.

Saludos

Comment: ¿y tienes algún link donde esté documentando esto que dices?

Comment: Gracias por la info.

Comment: @RuslanLópez no tengo el link a la documentación oficial, hace años que lo leí, pero puedes probarlo en la consola de rails, por ejemplo.  Te dejo un enlace a una pregunta similar donde también se explica: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395288/double-vs-single-quotes 
Saludos
Si te ha resuelto el problema puedes marcar la respuesta como valida? Gracias

Comment: @RuslanLópez https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#string

Answer (score 0):

En los lengujes de programacion la comilla simple hace un cast directo a string no valida caracteres especiales o variables.
Mientras que con las comillas doble se evalua el contenido del string en busca de varibles u caracteres especiales.

Comment: Creo que referirse a que esto sucede en "los lenguajes de programación" es demasiado. Cada lenguaje tiene sus propias reglas y sintaxis, no tiene por qué aplicarse a todos